# Set values to array and then do for each

Tags: vb.net

How would I set following into array:

```
Public Function opcijeMp(ByVal hwid As String)
    Dim hardware As String = hwid
    Dim result = New List(Of String)()
    Try
        ManageConnection(False, konekcija) 'Open connection'
        Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM info.opcije_mp as mp inner join instalacije as i where mp.idopcije_mp = 
        i.opcijeMP and i.instalacije_hwid  = '" + Globals.cpuid + "';"
        Dim SqlCmd As New MySqlCommand(strQuery, dbCon)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Globals.prodaja = reader.GetString("Prodaja")
            Globals.Kalkulacije = reader.GetString("Kalkulacije")
            Globals.Zaduznice = reader.GetString("Zaduznice")
            Globals.Predisponacije = reader.GetString("Predisponacije")
            Globals.Robno = reader.GetString("Robno")
            Globals.KUF = reader.GetString("KUF")
            Globals.KIF = reader.GetString("KIF")
            Globals.Narudzbenice = reader.GetString("Narudzbenice")
            Globals.Nalozi = reader.GetString("Nalozi")
            Globals.akcijskeCijene = reader.GetString("Akcijske_cijene")
            Globals.servisnaRoba = reader.GetString("Servisna_roba")
            Globals.Ostalo1 = reader.GetString("Ostalo1")
            Globals.Ostalo2 = reader.GetString("Ostalo2")
            Globals.Ostalo3 = reader.GetString("Ostalo3")
        End While
        reader.Close()
        'Vraća podatke u Listi stringova
        'Return result
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.ToString())
        Return Nothing
    Finally
        ManageConnection(True, konekcija)
    End Try
End Function
```

So i can use it in next function with for each loop:

```
 Dim s As String = Globals.prodaja
    Dim parts As String() = s.Split(New Char() {","c})
    Dim icona As String = parts(1)
    Dim barmanager1 As New BarManager
    Dim TileBarItem = New TileBarItem()
    TileBarItem.Content = parts(3)
    TileBarItem.Name = "ffss"
    TileBarItem.Width = 150
    Icon = New BitmapImage(New Uri("pack://application:,,,/DevExpress.Images.v16.1;component/Images/" + icona + ""))
    TileBarItem.TileGlyph = Icon
    TileBarItem.Background = New SolidColorBrush(DirectCast(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(parts(2)), Color))
    MessageBox.Show(parts(2))
    maloprodaja.Items.Add(TileBarItem)
```

Right now i have to run function for each variable i have stored in global variables class, i would like to add all the results from first function to one array in Globals and then run second function with for each loop to populate my tilebar

Comment: Create a class with properties and set them, then do what you want... or use a Dictionary, list(of)...

Comment: Ewww that code is so unnecessary, you could have researched list of and data tables in the space of time it took you to write that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using an external variable like `Globals` to pass data around is *extremely poor practice*. Your first function in the question should `return` the data, or alternatively it should return the MySqlDataReader. That will simplify what you're trying to do later on and effectively make this problem go away.

I also so saw this:

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM info.opcije_mp as mp inner join instalacije as i where mp.idopcije_mp = 
    i.opcijeMP and i.instalacije_hwid  = '" + Globals.cpuid + "';"
```

I want to highlight this part:

```
" ... and i.instalacije_hwid  = '" + Globals.cpuid + "';"
```

It's hard to understand just how bad that is. I can't think of a better way to get a program hacked. Google for parameterized queries and learn how to use them, rather than string concatentation, to put your cpuid into the sql statement.